# HTML5 web audio controls

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api

I have music play example http://www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio/example3.html

And i need to show html5 audio player (with controls) for this song. How i can do it?

Javascript code from example below:

```js
    // create the audio context (chrome only for now)
    // create the audio context (chrome only for now)
    if (! window.AudioContext) {
        if (! window.webkitAudioContext) {
            alert('no audiocontext found');
        }
        window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
    }
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var audioBuffer;
    var sourceNode;
    var analyser;
    var javascriptNode;

    // get the context from the canvas to draw on
    var ctx = $("#canvas").get()[0].getContext("2d");

    // create a gradient for the fill. Note the strange
    // offset, since the gradient is calculated based on
    // the canvas, not the specific element we draw
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,300);
    gradient.addColorStop(1,'#000000');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.75,'#ff0000');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.25,'#ffff00');
    gradient.addColorStop(0,'#ffffff');


    // load the sound
    setupAudioNodes();
    loadSound("http://www.audiotreasure.com/mp3/Bengali/04_john/04_john_04.mp3");


    function setupAudioNodes() {

        // setup a javascript node
        javascriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
        // connect to destination, else it isn't called
        javascriptNode.connect(context.destination);


        // setup a analyzer
        analyser = context.createAnalyser();
        analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
        analyser.fftSize = 512;

        // create a buffer source node
        sourceNode = context.createBufferSource();
        sourceNode.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(javascriptNode);

        sourceNode.connect(context.destination);
    }

    // load the specified sound
    function loadSound(url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        // When loaded decode the data
        request.onload = function() {

            // decode the data
            context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
                // when the audio is decoded play the sound
                playSound(buffer);
            }, onError);
        }
        request.send();
    }


    function playSound(buffer) {
        sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
        sourceNode.start(0);
    }

    // log if an error occurs
    function onError(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    // when the javascript node is called
    // we use information from the analyzer node
    // to draw the volume
    javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {

        // get the average for the first channel
        var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);

        // clear the current state
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 325);

        // set the fill style
        ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
        drawSpectrum(array);

    }


    function drawSpectrum(array) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < (array.length); i++ ){
            var value = array[i];

            ctx.fillRect(i*5,325-value,3,325);
            //  console.log([i,value])
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use an audio tag for your source and use createMediaElementSource to pass the audio to webaudio for visualization.

Beware that createMediaElementSource checks for CORS access so you must have appropriate cross-origin access for this to work.  (It looks like your audio source doesn't return the appropriate access headers for this to work.)

Comment: my server return all needed headers, i need only implement audio player.